# I want to extract the difference between the two times in swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to extract the difference between the two times in swiftui

between TimeOut and TimeIn :

```
       Section(header: Text("Date and time")) {
                HStack {
                    DatePicker("Date", selection: $todayDate, displayedComponents: .date)
                }  .datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
                HStack {
                    DatePicker("Time Out", selection: $inTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                }
                HStack {
                    DatePicker("Time In", selection: $outTime, displayedComponents: .hourAndMinute)
                }
                // Here I want to write the difference between the two times in the hour and the minute automatically ... ( Like : your permission is [1:00] or [1:30])
                Text("Here is the difference between the two times")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .lineLimit(2)
            }
```

Comment: Look at [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter)

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
func timeDiff(_ t1: Date, _ t2: Date) -> String {
    let m1 = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: t1)
    let h1 = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: t1)

    let m2 = Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: t2)
    let h2 = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: t2)
    // adjust the values as you see fit
    return "your permission is [\(abs(h2-h1)):\(abs(m2-m1))]"
}

....

Text(timeDiff(inTime, outTime))
```